# How to implement tittle bar with two images and one edittext in linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

Implementing tittle bar with two images and one edittext

Comment: please paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

remove title bar using

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
```

than add header with your requirement.